# Can Ctrl+Backspace be made to work in VS2008's Solution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm working in an ASP.NET MVC Beta 1 project, and I've noticed that if I want to rename a file in the Solution Explorer pane, Ctrl+Backspace does not do what it should (delete the closest "word"), and I get a silly box character and annoyed.

I'm doing this rather a lot as I'm using jTemplates, so rather than train myself out of using this very useful key combination, is there a way to make this function as expected in VS2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not. File a bug on connect.microsoft.com, and hope that they fix it in VS 2010.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this completely works, but if you go to Tools -> Options: Environemt -> Keyboard, you can set up short cuts.

Type "Rename" in the Show commands containing textbox.
Search for "File.Rename"

Put your cursor in the "Press shortcut keys" textbox and press Ctrl+Backspace.

Press Assign and it should take over the shortcut combination.

Hope that works for you.